# Receiving image spacial dimensions error when running object detection script

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, mask

I am trying to run my object detection script on an rtsp stream, but I keep receiving an error about the dimensions?

```
ValueError: The image has spatial dimensions (480, 720) but the mask has dimensions (15, 15)
```

I have already tried removing this error from visulization_utils and I have tried adjusting the camera resolution.

```
#Gets the object mask
detection_masks = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_masks:0')

# Initialize webcam feed
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
cap = VideoStream(src="rtsp://192.168.0.12/media/video1", resolution=(720,480), framerate=10).start()
time.sleep(2.0)
fps = FPS().start()

while(True):

    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    frame = cap.read()
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num, masks) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections, detection_masks],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        np.squeeze(masks).astype(np.uint8),
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.60)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)
```

I am trying to visualize scores, labels, boxes, and masks in real time.

Comment: just check the shape of the frame_expanded  object, make sure it's of the same shape to the shape of the image at the time of training tensorflow model.Tensorboard help you to monitor parameters

Comment: Ok I will try that, I trained on images that were 512 x 384 px. I'll see if I set the video stream to that if it will work.